# bitbake devtool not creating .bbappend

Tags: yocto, bitbake, yocto-recipe

I'm trying to change the `alsa-utils` recipe to add a `configure` option for the state dir. I need to move it to '/etc'.

I used `devtool` to modify, edit-recipe, and build without any issues. When I try to `update-recipe`, I get the following message:

> INFO: No patches or local source files needed updating

And it's not creating the .bbappend for my recipe changes. I haven't changed anything in the source directory.

Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: which command did you use? 'devtool extract' or 'devtool modify'?
'devtool extract' does not create any bbappend, but 'devtool modify' will.

Answer (score 1):

`update-recipe` creates a proper directory tree with .bbappend and .patch files in your layer only if you have commited any changes to the source directory.

If you don't want to create .bbappend manually, commit some changes to the source code you've got via `devtool`, run `update-recipe`, remove any reference to the patch file in your newly created recipe.